# Stackoverflow on Java JAX-WS

Tags: java, servlets, jax-ws, stack-overflow

I'm trying to make a servlet to handle add or updates to a JDBC database, the data is passed through POST and when i'm trying to create or edit some new data, gives a java.lang.StackOverflowError.

here's the code:

```
package servlet;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.netbeans.rest.application.config.JerseyTerrenos;
import org.netbeans.rest.application.config.Terrenos;

public class Sucessoterreno extends HttpServlet {

Terrenos terrenos = new Terrenos();
JerseyTerrenos jterrenos = new JerseyTerrenos();
Integer thebiggest = 0;

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> and
 * <code>POST</code> methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
    String coords = request.getParameter("coords");


    if (request.getParameter("id") != null) {
        terrenos = jterrenos.find_XML(Terrenos.class, request.getParameter("id"));
        terrenos.setTerrenosNome(nome);
        terrenos.setTerrenosCords(coords);

        jterrenos.edit_XML(terrenos);
    } else {
        ClientResponse clientResponse = jterrenos.findAll_XML(ClientResponse.class);
        GenericType<List<Terrenos>> gType = new GenericType<List<Terrenos>>() {
        };
        List<Terrenos> listterrenos;
        listterrenos = (clientResponse.getEntity(gType));
        for (int i = 0; i <= listterrenos.size(); i++) {
            if (thebiggest < listterrenos.iterator().next().getTerrenosId()) {
                thebiggest = listterrenos.get(i).getTerrenosId();
            }
        }
        terrenos.setTerrenosId(thebiggest);
        terrenos.setTerrenosNome(nome);
        terrenos.setTerrenosCords(coords);
        jterrenos.create_XML(terrenos);
    }

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        out.print("<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                + "<html>\n"
                + "    <head>\n"
                + "        <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n"
                + "        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"resources/style.css\">\n"
                + "        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"resources/reset.css\"/>\n"
                + "        <title>Florest Mapping - Terrenos</title>\n"
                + "    </head>\n"
                + "    <body>\n"
                + "        <div id=\"header\">\n"
                + "            <h1>Florest Mapping</h1><br>\n"
                + "        </div>\n"
                + "        <div id=\"content\">\n"
                + "            <ul id=\"coolMenu\">\n"
                + "                <li>\n"
                + "                    <a href=\"index.jsp\">Inicio</a>\n"
                + "                </li>\n"
                + "                <li>\n"
                + "                    <a href=\"#\">Equipas</a>\n"
                + "                    <ul class=\"noJS\">\n"
                + "                        <li><a href=\"equipa\">Criar Equipa</a></li>\n"
                + "                        <li><a href=\"listarterrenos\">Listar Equipas</a></li>\n"
                + "                    </ul>\n"
                + "                </li>\n"
                + "                <li>\n"
                + "                    <a href=\"#\">&Aacutereas</a>\n"
                + "                    <ul class=\"noJS\">\n"
                + "                        <li><a href=\"area\">Criar &aacuterea</a></li>\n"
                + "                        <li><a href=\"listarareas\">Listar &aacutereas</a></li>\n"
                + "                    </ul>\n"
                + "                </li>\n"
                + "                <li>\n"
                + "                    <a href=\"#\">Terrenos</a>\n"
                + "                    <ul class=\"noJS\">\n"
                + "                        <li><a href=\"terreno\">Criar Terreno</a></li>\n"
                + "                        <li><a href=\"listarterrenos\">Listar Terrenos</a></li>\n"
                + "                    </ul>\n"
                + "                </li>\n"
                + "            </ul>\n" + "<br><br><div id=\"main\">"
                + "            <h2>Criar Terreno</h2>\n");
        out.println("Terreno criado (ou editado) com Sucesso</div></div>\n");
        out.println("        <div id=\"footer\">\n"
                + "            2013 - Jo&atilde;o Correia\n"
                + "        </div>\n"
                + "    </body>\n"
                + "</html>");
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a recursive call:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    processRequest(request, response); // CALLS ITSELF
}
```

The stack trace can tell you that immediately: all stack trace elements will be at this `.processRequest()` method.

Comment: Thanks! I forget delete that, since i'm only using doPOST.

Comment: How can i make a stack trace? i'm newbie on java-ws.

Comment: Well, you did see the stack overflow error, didn't you? What follows the error is the stack trace